# TWRP Won't Flash Over CyanogenMod Recovery - Unable To Install Gapps

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-2, recovery-mode, google-apps

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS flashing a Samsung Galaxy S2 i9100 using Heimdall

I installed CyanogenMod using CWM, but it failed to install gapps. CM13 overwrote CWM and it's been impossible to flash TWRP over it. As far as I know, I need TWRP to install gapps, and I need it to use any apps on my phone.

The flashing of TWRP goes perfectly well on my computer and phone, according to what output it gives me, however there is no change of recovery. Everything is the exact same as it was before flashing.

I've turned off CM recovery updates and ADB sideload won't install the gapps zip file.

Comment: Have you tried flashing the twrp.img file with Flashify?

Comment: I have tried it, but it just says the download fails.